# Using Panda (pandastream) Video to show all videos in Index Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, pandastream

I'm using PandaVideo (http://www.pandastream.com/docs/integrate_with_rails) to upload videos in my Rails app. I'm having trouble taking the code from the docs at Panda and Heroku to relate it to the index action to show ALL of the videos, both on the Video's controller index action and on the User's profile to show each user's videos.

Here is the code that they give to find and show the video on the Video's SHOW action:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@original_video = @video.panda_video
@h264_encoding = @original_video.encodings["h264"]
```

then on the show view, I reference the video based on the last variable `@h264_encoding`

This works nicely. Now, I need to somehow take this code and use it to show all videos on a single page. For this example, let's show all of a particular user's videos on their page.

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  # not sure what goes here to find that user's videos (from Panda).
  # If i were just using paperclip for instance, I could easily write:
    @videos = @user.videos # but I need to use the Panda (the @h264_encoding variable) to find the video.
end
```

maybe this is useful...here is part of the video model

```
def panda_video
  @panda_video ||= Panda::Video.find(panda_video_id)
end
```

I hope I've provided enough code. If not please let me know and I'll add more. Again, I'm trying to show all of a particular user's videos from PandaStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but why wouldn't it be as simple as this:

```
def index
  @videos ||= Video.all
end
```

As far as your show, I see nothing wrong with this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  @videos = @user.videos
end
```

Then in your view something like the following:

```
<%= @videos.each do |video| %>
  <% h264_encoding = video.panda_video.encodings["h264"] %>
  <video id="movie" width="<%= h264_encoding.width %>" height="<%= h264_encoding.height %>" preload="none" 
    poster="<%= h264_encoding.screenshots.first %>" controls>
    <source src="<%= h264_encoding.url %>" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
<% end %>
```

You are simply referencing Panda's API to retrieve the information relating to an upload, however you handle all the relationships and the User and Video models.

Let me know if I'm missing something, as it seems you are on the right track.

Comment: It's amazing how sometimes the questions that are the hardest to solve require an easy solution. Thanks so much @omarvelous. That worked. I will award the bounty in 22 hours (when it allows me to).